# When to use IntentSender vs. PendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

The Android documentation describes both [`PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) and [`IntentSender`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.html) classes but it's not clear when or why you would use an `IntentSender` over a `PendingIntent` -- in fact much of the description appears to be identical for both.

The `PendingIntent` documentation:

> A description of an Intent and target action to perform with it. Instances of this class are created with (...); the returned object can be handed to other applications so that they can perform the action you described on your behalf at a later time.

The `IntentSender` documentation:

> A description of an Intent and target action to perform with it. The returned object can be handed to other applications so that they can perform the action you described on your behalf at a later time.

Both classes are `Parcelable` and both classes allow the receiver to invoke the action with `send` or `sendIntent` (with nearly identical signatures).

Since you need an existing `PendingIntent` to create an `IntentSender`, in what situation would you ever want to create an `IntentSender` rather than just using your `PendingIntent`?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this ? I'm facing the same issue but the only answer to this question doesn't give meaningul explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference which I notice is if I use **IntentSender** than launching activity launch in same task while **PendingIntent** create new task.

e.g:- Let suppose I have an app **MyApp** containing activity MyActivity and there is another app **SomeApp** and there is a functionality that clicking a button somehow MyActivity open above **SomeApp**'s activity.

Now When I pass MyActivity using **IntentSender** click on a button MyActivity is launched above the **SomeApp** and after click on home button I check there is only one task in the background i.e **SomeApp task**. But if i pass MyActivity in **PendingIntent** and click on home button of device than there is two task in background one is **SomeApp task** another is **MyApp task.**  So when you not want to perform operation in other task use IntentSender.

Answer (score -2):

There are really good examples and explanations [here](https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/the-android-intent-based-apis-part-seven-intentsenders-and-pendingintents/).

Here is a quick summary:

**IntentSender**

A IntentSender is an instance of `android.content.IntentSender`

Instances of `IntentSender` cannot be constructed directly but one can be obtained from a `android.app.PendingIntent` instance with `PendingIntent.getIntentSender()` since `PendingIntent` encapsulates an `IntentSender`.

[IntentSender Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.html)

**PendingIntent**

A `PendingIntent` is a token that you give to a foreign application (e.g `AlarmManager` or `AppWidgetManager`), which allows the foreign application to use your application's permissions to execute a predefined piece of code.

Basically, the foreign app that receives the `PendingIntent`, doesn't know the content of Intent which is wrapped by `PendingIntent` but the foreign app should be sending back the intent to main app when certai conditions are met.

[PendingIntent Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html/%22pendingIntent%20Documentation%22)

Comment: Your answers seem to be some parts of the document only. Hence not much useful. Can you clarify a bit more?